# Composing macros

Tags: macros

I have a macro `\lip` defined with xparse which takes several arguments.

I would like to define some macro `\slip` which applies macro `\eset` after macro `\lip`.

Is there a way to define `\slip` without defining a new macro with as many arguments as `\lip` and passing them to this latter command?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\eset}[1]{\mathchoice{\left \{#1\right \}}{\{#1\}}{\{#1\}}{\{#1\}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \lip { D||{A} m D||{B} m } {
  #1^#2, #3^#4
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


% How can I define slip without the xparse boilerplate?
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \slip {D||{A} m D||{B} m } {
  \eset{\lip |#1| {#2} |#3| {#4}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\lip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\[\slip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` at all there?

Comment: Is there any reason why not `\def\lip|#1|#2|#3|#4{#1^#2, #3^#4}`, then `\def\slip|#1|#2|#3|#4{\eset{#1^#2, #3^#4}}`?

Comment: Well this is a MWE, the complete `\lip` command is way more complicated than that :p

Comment: @FabianPijcke: Are you open to `\slip{ |a| {1} |b| {2}}\]`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, the \slip definition is fine except that the optional arguments (those between vertical bars) are no longer optional in slip.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would then prefer the long definition of slip, I prefer to bloat my preamble rather than my document, but this is still a nice idea :-)

Comment: @FabianPijcke: Well, I don't say it is impossible but if you want to maintain the optional arguments to exist for `\slip` there's not much that can be done other than repeat the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the doubts about `\eset` (it's wrong to begin with, in my opinion), you can incorporate it in `\lip`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\eset}[1]{\mathchoice{\left \{#1\right \}}{\{#1\}}{\{#1\}}{\{#1\}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \lip {s D||{A} m D||{B} m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \eset{#2^#3, #4^#5} }
   { #2^#3, #4^#5 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \slip {} { \lip* }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\lip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\[\slip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\end{document}
```

Avoid using a wealth of optional arguments: you'll lose yourself in trying to remember them.

In this particular case I see no connection between the syntax and the output, so a simpler

```
\NewDocumentCommand \lip {s O{A} m O{B} m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \eset{#2^#3, #4^#5} }
   { #2^#3, #4^#5 }
 }
```

with calls `\lip{x}{y}`, `\lip[u]{x}{y}`, `\lip{x}[v]{y}` or `\lip[u]{x}[v]{y}` would do better.

Why is the definition of `\eset` wrong? Because it's generally wrong to apply `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately.

If you want to accommodate other variants, you can use a slightly different strategy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\eset}[1]{\mathchoice{\left \{#1\right \}}{\{#1\}}{\{#1\}}{\{#1\}}}
\newcommand{\bset}[1]{[#1]}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \lip {o D||{A} m D||{B} m }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   { #2^#3, #4^#5 }
   { #1{#2^#3, #4^#5} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand \slip {} { \lip[\eset] }
\NewDocumentCommand \blip {} { \lip[\bset] }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\lip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\[\slip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\[\blip |a| {1} |b| {2}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the lip definition, each argument between vertical bars is directly related to the mandatory argument it is followed by, so I don't think it is problematic (which is why I avoided the standard square brackets notation). Besides I had several variations in mind (slip, Slip, rlip, Rlip, etc.), so your star notation, which I happily agree on its usefulness, is not exactly what I want :-( Thank you for your suggestion anyway, it is relevant to the question and deserves upvotes!